# Cassandra client driver timeout parameters

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I observed the following timeout parameters in Cassandra driver,

```
counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms: 5000
range_request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
request_timeout_in_ms: 10000
```

1) Could somebody explain what are these timeout in Cassandra driver?
2) What is the difference between request and read / write timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a list [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#configCassandra_yaml_r__PerformanceTuningProps) regarding the most important timeout parameters in Cassandra, but to also explain your question here:

- **range_request_timeout_in_ms**:
  The time that the coordinator waits for sequential or index scans to complete.
- **counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms** 
  The time that the coordinator waits for counter writes to complete. 
  *e.g: writing a table with counter column (counter is a special column for storing a number that is changed in increments.)* [Here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8878?focusedCommentId=14346748&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-14346748) you can find a good explanation on why the counter write needs separate timeout parameter.
- **read_request_timeout_in_ms**:
  The time that the coordinator waits for read operations to complete.
- **write_request_timeout_in_ms**:
  The time that the coordinator waits for write operations to complete.
- **request_timeout_in_ms**:
  The default time for other, miscellaneous operations.

Note:

1) **Coordinator:** *A node that receives a client query; it facilitates communication between all replica nodes responsible for the query (contacting at least n replica nodes to satisfy the query’s consistency level) and prepares and returns a result to the client.*

2) The timeout parameters are defined per node base (in cassandra.yaml) and not per client based.